# What's the grammar of "was as far as ever from realizing his dream of an independent Italian kingdom"?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pope_Julius_II#League_of_Cambrai_and_Holy_League

The sentence is:

> Although Julius had securely established papal authority in the region immediately around Rome was as far as ever from realizing his dream of an independent Italian kingdom.

---

I add a related question:

Is it necessary or better to exchange the positions of the noun ("Julius") and the pronoun ("he"), so that the noun is in the main clause?

"Although *he* had securely established papal authority in the region immediately around Rome, *Julius* was as far as ever from realizing his dream of an independent Italian kingdom."

---

[How to arrange the noun and its pronouns in a sentence?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/164710/how-to-arrange-the-noun-and-its-pronouns-in-a-sentence)

Comment: There's definitely something missing, but probably **he**. "**he** was as far as ever from realizing **his** dream"

Comment: @JavaLatte Is it necessary or better to exchange the positions of the noun ("Julius") and the pronoun ("he")?

"Although *he* had securely established papal authority in the region immediately around Rome, *Julius* was as far as ever from realizing his dream of an independent Italian kingdom."

Comment: For ease of reading, it is better to put the name in the first clause and the pronoun in the second clause. It is a matter of stylistic variation to swap them.

Comment: @JavaLatte How to arrange the noun and its pronouns in a sentence?(https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/164710/how-to-arrange-the-noun-and-its-pronouns-in-a-sentence)

Answer (score 1):

There should be a 'he' there. The subsequent 'his' makes this clear. The error has been corrected.

Comment: Is it necessary or better to exchange the positions of the noun ("Julius") and the pronoun ("he")?

"Although *he* had securely established papal authority in the region immediately around Rome, *Julius* was as far as ever from realizing his dream of an independent Italian kingdom."

Comment: Repairing an obvious omission is one thing; rewriting the sentence is another. The exchange is neither necessary nor does it make the sentence better, in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks. As a learner, I once was told, by a textbook, to place the noun in the main clause while to put its pronoun in the subordinate clauses.

Comment: That 'rule' is often ignored.

Comment: How to arrange the noun and its pronouns in a sentence?(https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/164710/how-to-arrange-the-noun-and-its-pronouns-in-a-sentence)